# Remove header from .MAT files loaded by loadmat() from scipy.io library

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, scipy, mat

I am new to both python and tensorflow.

I am trying to make a input pipeline for a generative adversarial network with input complex number data in .mat format and loaded it with loadmat() from scipy.io library. Now I am trying to prepare my data for giving input to my network and i tried from_tensor_slices(). But it can not be converted into tensor because of the headers in it. I looked up how to remove header from files by python and found some techniques that can be applied to .csv file but nothing on .mat files. How can I remove the header from .mat files? Also, the loadmat() function returns a list of dictionary I think. How can I extract the data from the file under such condition? Thank you.

Comment: `loadmat` returns a dictionary.  The `keys()` will look something like `dict_keys(['__header__', '__version__', '__globals__', 'A', 'B'])` (from a sample .mat).  Presumably the array(s) you want will have keys lilke `A` and `B`.  You can ignore the `__header__` key.

Comment: How do I ignore the '__header__' key? Thank you.

Comment: How do you ignore the key of any dictionary?  I don't understand what's your problem.  Are you talking about some other header than that `__header__` value in the `loadmat` `dict`?  Have you been able to access the variables/arrays in that file?  Without your file to look at I can only guess as to the content and what you do or do not want.

Comment: I think you need to show the `dict` as loaded (or part of it).  Also show the tensorflow command that is complaining about the header